# do related models have to have nested routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I'm starting to write my first app. Currently my (simplified) model structure looks like this:

```
- user account
    - profiles : many
        - money
        - level
        - rating
        - etc...
```

so a person can create an account, and can have multiple profiles under that account (almost like a RPG game, where you have many characters under one account). Each of these profiles can then have many different data points to save, like money, rating, etc... and some of these related models can have further nesting.

I'm in the process of setting up the routes for these, and I will be using resources in the `config/routes.rb`, but I don't want to nest all these resources.

Is it ok to declare each resource separately?

are there any long term/maintenance benefits to either approach (nesting vs not nesting)?

thanks for the help

Comment: The general philosophy is to avoid nesting beyond one level.  Secondly, it's totally acceptable to have nesting in addition to the flat access.  (The controller just has to check what was passed in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can route however you'd like to. Using Rails' resources or conventions in routing makes the process easier, but other than that, there is no real difference.

The only best practice I'm aware of is that you should ensure that the sections of the URL relate. For example:

```
/dog-food        # OK
/cat-food        # OK
/dogs/dog-food   # OK
/cats/dog-food   # NOT OK
```

The only time you'd preferably *WANT* to have a nested URL structure is if you're passing an identifier through the URL. Such as `/dogs/14/food` (where "14" is the ID of Dog). However, you can pass data across multiple pages in a variety of other ways as well.

Routes are very flexible, and you can do with them what you will. In your case, there's no issue with having `/money` to show all Users' lists of money. It wouldn't make sense to go that route, but you're certainly able to.

Just make sense and it'll make sense. Make sense?